# Preventing hover queue buildup

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-events

I am currently trying to create some sort of label that when you hover over will expand to show the user more information. The problem I'm having though is that when a user quickly hovers over the item multiple times, the event queue builds up and so the animation occurs multiple times.

I would like it that when the user hovers over the label, the hover event will be somehow disabled until the label info has been hidden again. I've tried using `.stop()` and `event.stopPropagation()` but neither of these had the desired effect. Does anyone have any other ideas?

My code can be seen below:

```
$('.label').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.label-info').slideDown('slow');
});

$('.label').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.label-info').slideUp('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.stop()`:

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

So your code should look like this:

```
$('.label')
.mouseenter(function(){
    $('.label-info').stop(1,1).slideDown('slow');
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $('.label-info').stop(1,1).slideUp('slow');
})
```

Note that it is unwise to use only a class selector if you are targeting IE 7 and below.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem a few times, and have come up with various ways to get around it. Here are just 2 approaches you could take to help rid this problem.

### Option 1 : Filtering animated elements

Using a combination of [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) and [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) we can prevent the animation from taking place if it is already mid-animation. This will mean it will slide all the way up, before sliding down.

```
$('.label').mouseenter(function()
{
    $('.label-info').filter(':animated').slideDown('slow');
}).mouseleave(function()
{
    $('.label-info').filter(':animated').slideUp('slow');
})
```

### Option 2 - [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin

hoverIntent is a nice little jQuery plugin that helps prevent accidental mousing over-out of elements by adding a short delay before triggering the hover event. It's a really useful plugin, not only for helping to resolve this problem, but also if you've got highly interactive DOM elements.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, should it not be filtered by when it's not animated?

Comment: oops, there was a typo, both were sliding down. Try now! :)